# Camel servlet is giving javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception during handshake with endpoint. How to enable TLSv1.2 for camel servlet

Tags: tls1.2

We are using camel servlet to connect to endpoint URL for fetching data from services. After endpoint URL blocks TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 we are getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. My application is running on jboss 7 with JDK 1.7. We have explicitly enabled TLSv1.2 protocol using system property -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 but still I'm getting SSLHandshakeException. I want to know how to enable TLSv1.2 protocol for camel servlet.